# Listening to incoming whatsapp messages

Tags: sockets, whatsapp

I have joined multiple groups on my whatsapp which generate hundreds of messages daily. Some of them might concern me, while others might not. So I wanted to find out is there a way (using some api, scripting or whatever) to listen to every incoming group message and on finding specific keywords in those messages perform certain operation (such as sending me a notification).

Open to ideas. Thanks in advance.